# How can I View.performClick() on a specific coordinates?

Tags: android, android-webview, touch-event

I am trying to perform click on an input field in `Webview`, I want to trigger a tap event programmatically so that the input field get focused and the keyboard will show.

I tried injecting JavaScript and calling the `.focus()` method and also I tried triggering `.click()` event, but nothing seems to work, so I though maybe there might way to simulate the same touch event outside the webview.

I used `View.performClick()` before to trigger a click event on button before, maybe if you could tell the `performClick` method to click on a specific coordinates that might trigger the same user touch event. But I searched through the docs I couldn't find anything.

How can approach this problem?